# Why clang-tidy readability-isolate-declaration not fixing code?

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

I tried to use readability-isolate-declaration check in clang-tidy, but nothing fixed. Example of code from test.cpp file:

```
void f() {
    int a = 0, b = 1, c = 2;
}
```

What I've done:

```
clang-tidy -checks='readability-isolate-declaration' -fix test.cpp
```

Output:

```
Error while trying to load a compilation database:
Could not auto-detect compilation database for file "test.cpp"
No compilation database found in /home/anzipex/Downloads/clang-test or any parent directory
fixed-compilation-database: Error while opening fixed database: No such file or directory
json-compilation-database: Error while opening JSON database: No such file or directory
Running without flags.
```

Comment: "clang-tidy --version" shows LLVM version 6.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. `readability-isolate-declaration` check didn't exist in clang-tidy 6. Upgrade to a more recent version
2. If you don't have a compilation database, you can use `--`(double dash) to specify compilation options. Even if you specify none, this will tell clang-tidy to compile the file. See the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/#id2).
3. You didn't tell clang-tidy to exclude other checks besides the one you want

This is what the command should look like:

`clang-tidy -checks='-*,readability-isolate-declaration' test.cpp -fix --`

Output:

```
void f() {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 2;
}
```